# Mysql reset delimiter to normal ';'

Tags: mysql, strange-attractor

I have typed:

```
DELIMITER DELIMITER
```

Just trying to figure it out how to set my delimiter to normal ';' again;

Comment: `DELIMITER ;` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you set a different delimiter all the query statement will expect that delimiter to be used

```
delimiter delimiter 

select * from users ; // This would do nothing
```

But

```
select * from users delimiter
```

will list the users since once it encounters `delimiter` which is your defined delimiter the statement will be executed.

To go back you need to use

`delimiter ;`